# Brown Tips on Oregano Cuttings

Tags: cuttings

My oregano cuttings have become brown at the tips and are dropping leaves. They are planted indoors with a room temp around 70. What reasons could they be dropping leaves?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like some sort of fungal infection.  I found an article on taking [herb cuttings](https://learningherbs.com/skills/herbs-from-cuttings/) that recommends sterilizing the scissors and changing the water every day or two to reduce bacteria and algae growth.  If the leaves in particular are submerged in water they will rot so perhaps this was the start of your problem.  There is a lot of good advice in the article and comments like taking cuttings from healthy disease free plants, avoiding distilled or chlorinated water, adding a few drops of raw apple cider vinegar for trace minterals and so on.